# Can python packages be distributed via the MS Store (MSIX)?

Tags: python, windows-store, msix

Assuming we have a working Python app (in this case, [PythonTurtle](http://pythonturtle.org/)) which we would like to distribute via the Microsoft Store, is it possible to package it as an MSIX and allow users to easily install it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If this app does not need any of [these limited resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) then it should work.

You can use the [MS tooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/) or [Advanced Installer Express](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html) edition.

If you have any issues I would love to help (pro-bono), ping me at bogdan at advancedinstaller dot com.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer*